# Hive table join with update

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql, join

I am a bit stuck , Can any one help me here. I have two tables with the below structure.

```
Table 1
Id String
Code1 String
Code2 String

Table 2
Id String
UserCode String
UniversalCode String
```

What i need to do is to replace all value in code1 and code2 with UniversalCode from the table 2. To be more clear , if code1 matches UserCode then repalce Code1 with universalCode and again for the same record if code2 matches with usercode then replace it with UniversalCode. If there is no match retain the value for code1 and code2. I need to have all records from table 1. Table 1 and Table 2 are connected via Id.

I tried the below for one column but got stuck adding code2

```
SELECT 
Id,
CASE WHEN a.Code1 = b.UserCode then b.UniversalCode else a.Code1 end
from table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON (a.Id = b.Id and a.code1 = b.UserCode);
```

Any suggestions to get this done ? , The real scenario has 5-6 columns where i need to apply the same logic.

```
Test Data 

Table 1
1,123,ABCD
1,ABCD,123
1,456,BCD
1,BCD,789
1,789,100

Table 2 
1,123,XXX
1,456,YYY
1,789,ZZZ
2,123,XXX
2,456,YYY
2,789,ZZZ

Output 
1,XXX,ABCD
1,ABCD,XXX
1,YYY,BCD
1,BCD,ZZZ
1,ZZZ,100


output with a.id=b.id in Join(Please refer below comments for this output)
1       123     XXX     100     100
1       123     123     100     100
1       123     123     100     100
1       ABCD    ABCD    101     101
1       ABCD    ABCD    101     101
1       ABCD    ABCD    101     101
1       456     456     DEF     DEF
1       456     YYY     DEF     DEF
1       456     456     DEF     DEF
1       BCD     BCD     789     789
1       BCD     BCD     789     789
1       BCD     BCD     789     ZZZ
1       789     789     CDE     CDE
1       789     789     CDE     CDE
1       789     ZZZ     CDE     CDE
1       100     100     HBT     HBT
1       100     100     HBT     HBT
1       100     100     HBT     HBT
1       100     100     123     XXX
1       100     100     123     123
1       100     100     123     123
```

Comment: use `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @vkp : Okay, but  how do i add the logic for the second column . I was stuck at that point.

Comment: yes..you would have to repeat it as many times for as many columns you wish to change

Comment: @vkp: If you look at the join condition i have used Id and Code1 in it. I Can add Code2 as well into the On condition but that will result in an incorrect answer right

Comment: i think `a.id=b.id` will suffice in the `join` clause.

Comment: @vkp : I have added the test data , if you see, if i add a.id=b.id it will through me 15 entries in the output right. Since for each id in Table 1 there are three entries in table 2 . I am very bad with SQL and cant get my way out of this. Somebody call 911 !!

Comment: no..you are talking about a `cross join` where the output rows = rows in table1 *  rows in table2. Try it with only `a.id = b.id` in the `join`

Comment: @vkp: Yeah i will check that again, but i got a question if you can help me understand this. a.id=b.id . When i use left outer join , a single row in table 1 matches with 3 rows in table b. (Id =1 for row 1 and in table 2 there are three rows with Id=1) how does system understand which one to match ?

Comment: you are specifying it in the `case` statement, which ones to match.

Comment: @vkp: I tried and as i was hinting its more of a cross product that comes in the output. I have updated the output in my initial post. I will try out the way madhu has suggested and has another way with multiple left joins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you but something like this should help you.

```
SELECT 
     a.Id
   , CASE WHEN a.Code1 = b.UserCode THEN b.UniversalCode ELSE a.Code1 END AS Code1
   , CASE WHEN a.Code2 = b.UserCode THEN b.UniversalCode ELSE a.Code2 END AS Code2
FROM    table1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        table2 b 
        ON a.Id = b.Id;
```

Comment: Yes i tried the above. The issue with this is that for each entry in table 1(a) there are three entries in Table 2(b). Which i believe would result in incorrect answer with more records than expected. I have added a test data just in case if you are confused.

Comment: Could you write here and example of the expected output please? use your test data

Comment: 1,123,ABCD ,(First Row) in table 1 matches with 3 rows in table 2 <1,123,XXX> ,<1,456,YYY> ,<1,789,ZZZ> .  (Matching key being ( Id) .Code 1 (123) matches with UserCode(123) in second table. So replace code 1 by XXX(UniversalCode). Now code 2 (ABCD) doesnt have a match and hence retained the value ABCD. The output of then is  1,XXX,ABCD . Similar logic has to applied for all records. If code 1 matches replace or else retain. If code 2 match replace or retain.

Comment: I don't see the problem buddy, the code I write above will give you that output because you are matching the UserCode in the CASE statement.

Comment: Let me give it a try again then. Thanks :)

Comment: I have update the output as per your suggestion on to the ticket under output with a.id=b.id in Join. This results in a cross product. I have another way to solve this with multiple left joins . Just in case if there is another better way please do let me know. Would love to learn more on this

Comment: You could use SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT

Answer (score 0):

We can try the below query:-

```
 SELECT 
    Id,
    CASE WHEN Code1 = UserCode then UniversalCode else Code1 end,
    CASE WHEN Code2= UserCode then UniversalCode else Code2 end
    from
    (select a.id,a.Code1,a.Code2,b.UserCode,b.UniversalCode
    from table1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON (a.Id = b.Id and a.code1 = b.UserCode) union 
    select a.id,a.Code1,a.Code2,b.UserCode,b.UniversalCode
    from table1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON (a.Id = b.Id and a.code1 = b.UniversalCode)) dat ;
```

Comment: I will try it out. I finally did it with multiple left outer joins. Thanks for the tip. Much appreciated .